# Jquery UI: Presetting a slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

This is a such a head scratcher!

This slider works fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/EuTA8/

```
 $("#s2").slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 200,
        step: .1,
        value: 100.0,
        values: [200.0],
        slide: function(event, ui) {
           for (var i = 0; i < ui.values.length; ++i) {
              $("input.v2[data-index=" + i + "]").val(ui.values[i]+ " %");
           }
        }
});
```

But I want to preset the position of the slider at '100.0'.
Despite having the attribute that should do this:

```
    value: 100.0,
```

...jquery UI just ignores it an puts the slider at the maximum setting.

I take the square brackets (should they even be there?!) off the values attribute to create:

```
    values: 200.0,
```

And the slider position presets beautifully. But now, I can't drag the slider! See what I mean here:

http://jsfiddle.net/EuTA8/1/

What is going on? All I need to do is preset the position. (Don't worry about the value in the input element.)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#s2").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 200,
    step: .1,
    value: 100.0,
    values: [100.0],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
       for (var i = 0; i < ui.values.length; ++i) {
          $("input.v2[data-index=" + i + "]").val(ui.values[i]+ " %");
       }
    }
});
```

Change `[200.0]` to `[100.0]`

Comment: Well done! Where can I find information on what exactly I was doing wrong? I thought "values" meant "the number of values in a slider"?

Comment: @Starkers: "values" doesn't mean the number of values in the slider, but just at which positions you want to put the slider: you can add more than one: http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range

Comment: @Starkers ProgramFOX pretty much sums it up :)

Comment: Ahh thankyou that makes so much sense. My values array was overriding my value attr, making me think there was a ghost in the machine!

Comment: @Starkers haha, hate it when the old programming ghost pops up :P

Comment: I must be living on an Indian burial site the amount I get!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("#s2").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 200,
    step: .1,
    values: [100.0]
    slide: function(event, ui) {
       for (var i = 0; i < ui.values.length; ++i) {
          $("input.v2[data-index=" + i + "]").val(ui.values[i]+ " %");
       }
    }
});
```

You can simply remove the `value: 100.0` line, and change `values: [200]` into `values: [100]`

And yes, the square brackets should be there, because `values` is an array.